# make comparisons between 2 dice toss in an IOS app

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, xcode, uiimageview

I have an app with 2 image views. each one randomly displays an image of a dice face (from 1 to 6), the end results looks like the simulation of a dice toss for a player and for the computer.

it looks like this :

[image]

I have an array that contains the names for each image that is displayed :
`let des: Array = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six"]`

I also have a function that randomizes the image that is displayed for the 2 players

```
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
            self.dicePlayer.image = UIImage(named: self.des.randomElement() ?? "one")
            self.diceComputer.image = UIImage(named: self.des.randomElement() ?? "two")

        }
        // on appelle la fonction qui gere les scores
        gestionDesScores()
    }
```

I would like to make comparison between those 2 tosses (i.e : if player one dice toss is superior to player 2 toss, then the player wins and vice versa).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend storing the two tosses as human readable `Int` values.  Add these properties to your class:

```
var playerToss = 1
var computerToss = 1
```

Then modify your function like this:

```
func lancerDeDes() {
    self.playerToss = Int.random(in: 1...6)
    self.computerToss = Int.random(in: 1...6)

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
        // subtract 1 because des array is indexed 0...5 not 1...6
        self.dicePlayer.image = UIImage(named: self.des[self.playerToss - 1])
        self.diceComputer.image = UIImage(named: self.des[self.computerToss - 1])

    }
    // on appelle la fonction qui gere les scores
    gestionDesScores()
}
```

Then you can just compare `playerToss` and `computerToss` directly:

```
if self.playerToss > self.computerToss {
    // the player wins!
}
```

Storing the values as `Int` will aid you in debugging in addition to making the comparison easier.

---

**Magic Numbers**

In your program, I think it is clear what `6` represents.  In general though it is wise to avoid *magic numbers* (uncommented numbers) in your code.  So you could write the rolls as:

```
self.playerToss = Int.random(in: des.indices) + 1
self.computerToss = Int.random(in: des.indices) + 1
```

By using `des.indices` to obtain the range `0...5` from the `des` array, you ensure that the code would work correctly even if the number of values in the `des` array changed.

I personally would still store the rolls in the range `1...6` for debugging purposes, but you could avoid the `+ 1` and `- 1` by storing the rolls in the range `0...5`.

Answer (score 2):

Have your dice values in an enum:

```
enum Die: String,CaseIterable{
    case One    = "one"
    case Two    = "two"
    case Three  = "three"
    case Four   = "four"
    case Five   = "five"
    case Six    = "six"
}
```

Add an extension :

```
extension CaseIterable where Self: Equatable {
    var index: Self.AllCases.Index? {
        return Self.allCases.firstIndex { self == $0 }
    }
}
```

And your throwDie method can look like :

```
    func throwDice(){
        let userResult = Die.allCases.randomElement()
        let computerResult = Die.allCases.randomElement()

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: {
            self.dicePlayer.image = UIImage(named: userResult?.rawValue ?? "one")
            self.diceComputer.image = UIImage(named: computerResult?.rawValue ?? "one")
        }) { (_) in
            print("Index Value : \(computerResult?.index) : \(computerResult?.rawValue)")
            //You may use the indexValue for comparison and the rawValue to assign your image
        }
    }
```

Self explanatory, I believe.

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
let fImg = self.des.randomElement() ?? "one"
let sImg = self.des.randomElement() ?? "two"  
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
   self.dicePlayer.image = UIImage(named:fImg)
   self.diceComputer.image = UIImage(named:sImg) 
}
```

Then

```
if let fIndex = des.index(of:fImg) , 
   let sIndex = des.index(of:sImg) , 
   fIndex == (sIndex - 1) {
   // wins 
}
```